# Filling in MBeanParameterInfo

Tags: java, jmx

When looking at the MBean for my application in the MBeans tab in JConsole there are submenus for 'Attributes' and 'Operations'.  If these tree structures are expanded to their maximum extent and then one of the operations is clicked on, the panel on the right presents three sections: Operation invocation, MBeanOperationInfo and Descriptor.  My question relates to the 2nd.

How can you populate the MBeanOperationalInfo?  I have tried adding standard javadoc to the MBean interface but that does not work.  It would be really useful to be able to document the parameters - especially as their names decay to p1,p2,...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your MBean must be a [DynamicMBean](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/DynamicMBean.html) and implement the method [getMBeanInfo()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/DynamicMBean.html#getMBeanInfo%28%29). This also works for Open MBean and Model MBean.

There is an example here: http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/816-7609/6mdjrf83d?a=view

Answer (score 1):

While being a DynamicMBean will work for this, it appears to no longer be necessary. The [Dynamic MBeans section of the Best Practices](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/best-practices-jsp-136021.html#mozTocId963066) on Oracle's JMX site indicates that subclassing StandardMBean would be preferable unless there are other reasons for making your MBean dynamic:

> It is almost never necessary to implement the DynamicMBean interface for an MBean whose management interface is known at compile time. If you need some particular abilities of Dynamic MBeans, for example the ability to supply descriptions for the attributes or operations, or the ability to disable certain attributes or operations, then you should consider subclassing javax.management.StandardMBean rather than implementing the DynamicMBean interface. That means that the management interface is still described by a Java interface, which in turn means that clients can use that interface to make a proxy for convenient access.